# Setup GAE project with Resteasy using Maven in Eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, resteasy

I am trying to learn Maven and to that end I want to create a project in Eclipse 4.3 targetting the GAE (latest version: 1.8.4) and using Maven for building/dependency management. I want to include Resteasy and CDI, but for the time being I have problems with Resteasy.

What have I done:

- Followed [this guide](https://coderforchrist.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/getting-maven-gae-and-eclipse-working-together/) (without the Jersey part) to setup a Maven/Eclipse/GAE project. I had to change the Java source and target configuration to 1.7 and it worked great.
- To include Resteasy:

  - Added the following dependencies:

    ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    ```
  - Implemented `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`.
  - And the following configuration in web.xml:

    ```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>npara.expenses.server.JaxRsApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ```

When running the project, using the launch configuration created by Maven, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
```

The `HttpServletDispatcher` is located in resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final.jar, which is correctly placed in WEB-INF/lib. I already have created a similar project using GAE, Resteasy, CDI *without Maven* (manual JAR management) and this exact configuration and it works perfectly.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) it is easier to use.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```